# Confidence interval for non i.i.d. sample

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I'm facing this machine learning problem in real life, that turns to stem from a statistics problem. Given a test set S of size N samples with a statistic x (x is the mean accuracy across the N samples), I want to know if the test set S is large enough for my prescribed confidence interval width and confidence level (otherwise, I'll collect more test samples).

If my N samples are i.i.d, the theory is commonly found online and is rather straightforward. However, I know there are some dependencies between my samples. If I assume i.i.d. (which doesn't hold), I can compute my sample variance and get the needed sample size N' for my given prescribed confidence interval width and confidence level, but I find that in practice this N' is not large enough. This makes sense to me intuitively, since the correlations in the data would kind of make the actual effective sample size smaller.

I find some methods that rely on bootstrapping like http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/PostScript/InterneArbeiten/Bisani_BootstrapEstimatesForConfidenceIntervalsInASRPerformanceEvaluation_ICASSP_2004.pdf, but they assume I know how to split my data into non--correlated subsets, which I don't.

My question is what is a correct or practical way to approach the question "is my test set large enough for my prescribed confidence interval width and confidence level, when my samples are non i.i.d.?"

Comment: Are your samples iid conditional on measured variables?

Comment: not sure what that means, but I assume no

Comment: You think there are some dependencies between your samples. I'm wondering if you know what the source of that dependence is (e.g., are units sampled from schools, workplaces, etc). And if so, have you measured those clustering variables?

Comment: So this is for ASR evaluation. Samples are dependent because some share the same speaker, accent, etc. But I would like to avoid manually analyzing the dependency structure, and have a methods that is as general as possible